# React js : Audio element's src is updating on setState but the audioRef is not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

please help me! I'm using context API to pass the tracks to MucsicPlayer. but whenever I set setTracks state audio element src updates  but audioRef.current doesn't update. I inspected it and saw that audioRef.current = <audio preload="auto" src(unknown)>. so ref src does not update. what should I do.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext } from 'react'
import { TrackContext } from '../../music/TrackContext'

const MusicPlayer = () => {

    const [tracks, setTracks] = useContext(TrackContext)
    console.log(tracks)
    // states
    const [trackIndex, setTrackIndex] = useState(0)
    console.log(trackIndex)
    const [trackProgress, setTrackProgress] = useState(0)
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const [volume, setVolume] = useState(1)
    const { title, artist, image, audioSrc } = tracks[trackIndex]

    //refs
    const audio = new Audio(audioSrc)
    const audioRef = useRef(audio)
    const intervalRef = useRef()
    const isReady = useRef(false)
    console.log(audioRef.current)
    const { duration } = audioRef.current
    const toPrevTrack = () => {
        if (trackIndex - 1 < 0) {
            setTrackIndex(tracks.length - 1)
        } else {
            setTrackIndex(trackIndex - 1)
        }
    }

    const toNextTrack = () => {
        if (trackIndex < tracks.length - 1) {
            setTrackIndex(trackIndex + 1)
        } else {
            setTrackIndex(0)
        }
    }


    const startTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current)

        intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
            if (audioRef.current.ended) {
                toNextTrack()
            } else {
                setTrackProgress(audioRef.current.currentTime);
            }
        }, [1000])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            audioRef.current.play()

            startTimer();
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
            audioRef.current.pause()
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [isPlaying])

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            audioRef.current.pause()
            clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        audioRef.current.play()
        audioRef.current = new Audio(audioSrc)
        setTrackProgress(audioRef.current.currentTime)

        if (isReady.current) {
            audioRef.current.play()
            setIsPlaying(true)
            startTimer()
        } else {
            isReady.current = true
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [trackIndex])
    const onScrub = (value) => {
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
        audioRef.current.currentTime = value
        setTrackProgress(audioRef.current.currentTime)
    }

    const onScrubEnd = () => {
        if (!isPlaying) {
            setIsPlaying(true);
        }
        startTimer();
    }

    const onScrubVolume = (value) => {
        audioRef.current.volume = value
        setVolume(audioRef.current.value)
    }

    function formatMinutes(sec) {
        return new Date(sec * 1000).toUTCString().split(" ")[4].substr(3, 8)
    }

    const currentPercentage = duration ? `${(trackProgress / duration) * 100}%` : '0%';
    const trackStyling = `-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, color-stop(${currentPercentage}, #fff), color-stop(${currentPercentage}, #777))`;

   
    return (
        <div className="player">
            <div className="left-block">
                <div className="art">
                    <img src={image} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="song-details">
                    <div className="song-name">{title}</div>
                    <div className="artist-name">
                        <a href="sa">{artist}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="center-block">
                <div className="song-progress">
                    <div>{formatMinutes(audioRef.current.currentTime)}</div>
                    <input
                        value={trackProgress}
                        step="1"
                        min="1"
                        max={duration ? duration : `${duration}`}
                        onChange={(e) => onScrub(e.target.value)}
                        onMouseUp={onScrubEnd}
                        onKeyUp={onScrubEnd}
                        style={{ background: trackStyling }}
                        type="range" />
                    <div>{duration ? formatMinutes(duration) : "00:00"}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default MusicPlayer
```

Answer (score 1):

`useRef` will not get re-initialized on every render.

So it will stay the same as it was initialized the very first time.

So whenever you are switching your track you have to update the audioRef too.

Change your `toPrevTrack` and `toNextTrack`

```
const toPrevTrack = () => {
   const prevIndex = trackIndex - 1 < 0 ? tracks.length - 1 : trackIndex - 1;
   const { audioSrc } = tracks[prevIndex]
   audioRef.current = new Audio(audioSrc);
}

const toNextTrack = () => {
   const nextIndex = trackIndex < tracks.length - 1 ? trackIndex + 1 : 0;
   const { audioSrc } = tracks[nextIndex]
   audioRef.current = new Audio(audioSrc);
}
```